# How is /etc/default/grub generated during installation?

Tags: grub2

I'm currently working on a project that needs kernel boot parameters added during a custom adapted Ubuntu installer (based on 14.04.3).

I know that

- they belong into `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`.
- one can add configuration files to `/etc/default/grub.d` in order to influence the generation of `/etc/default/grub`.
- the default `grub` seems to be available as `/usr/share/grub/default/grub`.
- `grub-mkconfig` then takes the scripts from `/etc/grub.d` and settings from `/etc/default/grub` and generates `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

My current problem is the following: Two of my packages and `mdadm` place files into `/etc/default/grub.d`, all of them altering `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. But for some reason, one of my files gets ignored. And I can't really find when or by what `/etc/default/grub` is created initially created or how I could regenerate it.

Comment: Are both files executable? `grub-mkconfig` sources for executable files in `grub.d`.

Comment: Actually none of the three are executable. AFAIK, `grub-mkconfig` searches in `/etc/grub.d` but not `/etc/default/grub.d`.

Answer (score 3):

`/etc/default/grub` is created by the `grub-pc` post-installation script. You can probably regenerate in using

```
dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc
```

although I haven't tested it.

Comment: It looks like it does half the job... I removed `/etc/default/grub` and ran `dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc` which didn't re-create `/etc/default/grub` but somehow `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` with the parameters from all 3 cfg files.

Comment: you'll need to force the recreation of the deleted configuration file using `UCF_FORCE_CONFFMISS=Yes dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc`

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays another way is to rename current /etc/default/grub and restore it to default with

```
sudo cp /usr/share/grub/default/grub /etc/default/grub
```

Comment: That's a bingo!