# Ubuntu 22.04 Software Updater Error: E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: apt, grub2, package-management, 22.04, dpkg

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 , at some point when using the software updater I got a software index error message. After trying "continue" using sudo ap-get install -f in terminal to fix it I got the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 13.8 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 223017 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic (6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-26-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 9: /etc/default/grub: GRUB_TERMINAL: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I searched for this in many sites but still have issues. I am not an expert in linux, what can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is /etc/default/grub generated during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774678/how-is-etc-default-grub-generated-during-installation)

Comment: @nobody Hi!. It is not the same problem. Here dpkg is broken.

Comment: @GAD3R are you sure? It seems to me somehow `/etc/default/grub` is broken so dpkg interrupts.

Comment: @nobody The main problem is the exit status of `dpkg`, isn't `0`.

Comment: You have a bad line in etc/default/grub, the one with TERMINAL in it. Did you mistakenly uncomment that line? Always read the error messages carefully.

Comment: `GRUB_TERMINAL: not found` suggests you've altered what should be a variable assignment like `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` to something that would be parsed as a command + args like `GRUB_TERMINAL = console`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To solve the following error:

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Create a `/var/lib/dpkg/info/file.postrm` in your case the file name is:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic.postrm
```

only with the following lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/true
```

then:

```
chmod +x /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic.postrm
```

run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt remove linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic
```

By default, the `GRUB_TERMINAL` is commented in your `/etc/default/grub` :

```
 sudo sed -e '/GRUB_TERMINAL/s/^/#/' -i /etc/default/grub
 sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Will this fix the grub error?

Comment: @OrganicMarble See my edit.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestions took care of the errors! -